# SDL2 and C++ regarding image animation following a line

Tags: c++, sdl

I am writing a turtle class that would allows for movement for drawing. I am not using any game loop for it. User of this turtle object
will issue command like:

```
Turtle t;
t.forward(50);
t.left(90);
```

The Turtle constructor takes cares of the window and renderer creation.
All interaction is through programming. No polling of any type of keyboard events. Right now I am able to render a spiral animation using the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    Turtle t;
    t.clear();

    t.color("red");
    int numofside = 100;
    t.shape("seaturtle");

    for (int i=0; i<numofside; i++)
    {
      t.forward(i + 5);
      t.left(75);
      SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer);
      SDL_Delay(50);
    }

    SDL_Delay(5000);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

The big issue now is how to have the seaturtle image follow the line that is being rendered?

I understand the concept to do animation in SDL2 using frame (loop) ie clear screen, render at current position, increase x,y position.

But I cannot clear the screen as it will clear my existing lines that have been drawn.

Is there any SDL texture function that can make an image show and hide without deleting the whole screen? or any idea of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the "turtle" using XOR. Then you redraw it to erase it.

You could also keep track of the lines drawn, so you can redraw them all if you erase the display.

Or you could use multiple drawing surfaces. One for the "background", one for the lines you draw, and one for the "turtle". Then you draw/erase/redraw the turtle surface only as it moves, and finally draw all layers on top of each other to display it. A kind of multi-buffer approach.

Answer (score 1):

Save whatever you'd draw, say, put them in a vector (via an abstract base class `DrawInstruction*`). Then you can redraw after clear screen. The vector is either global or, better yet, a member of your `Turtle` class.